# Directly opening the standard dialer, without using an intent chooser

Tags: android

Is it possible to open android dialer directly. The standard solution (via Intent.ACTION_DIAL) does not suit me, because it create intent chooser, and there are other dialer apps, like viber. Any solutions?

Comment: What exactly is "android dialer"? After all, there are ~2 billion Android devices spread over 20,000+ device models, with dozens or hundreds of different pre-installed dialers.

Comment: Yea, that's m problem.. So I want to make sure that possible solution does not exict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to directly open the dialer because you cant tell all the dialers package names on all the vendors, for instance a Xiaomi dialer would have a different package name than the LG one.
The only way is to use Intents to ask the OS to open the dialer, if there is a default dialer selected it will open the default one, if default is not selected the user will be asked to choose. 
This is the correct and expected behavior and is made so for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for response Mark